# Inequality Proof: $x^ay^b\leq x^{a+b}+y^{a+b}$

Tags: inequality

$\forall a,b\in \mathbb{Z}, ~\forall a,b\geq 0$ and $x,y>0$ How to show that :
$$
x^ay^b\leq x^{a+b}+y^{a+b}
$$

Comment: If $x,y\geq 1$ it is easy to prove that $$x^ay^b\leq \max\left(x^{a+b},y^{a+b}\right).$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide by the left-hand side, and you want to show that $$1\leq\left(\frac xy\right)^b+\left(\frac yx\right)^a$$
One of the right-hand terms is clearly at least 1.

Answer (score 2):

$$ (x^a-y^a)(x^b-y^b)=x^{a+b}+y^{a+b} -x^{a}y^{b} -x^{b}y^a$$

Now, since $a,b\geq 0$, show that if $x^a\leq y^a$ then $x^b\leq y^b$, and if $x^a\geq y^a$ then $x^b\geq y^b$.

So the left hand side is non-negative, showing the stronger result:

$$x^{a}y^{b} +x^{b}y^a\leq x^{a+b}+y^{a+b}$$